# Is $\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}\{x:f(x) > \frac{1}{n}\}=\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}\{x:f(x) \geq \frac{1}{n}\}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I am learning real analysis recently, I know that $$\{x:f(x) > \frac{1}{n}\} = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\{x:f(x) > 0\}$$ but does it equal to $$\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\{x:f(x)\geq \frac{1}{n}\}$$ and why?

Comment: $\{x:f(x) > \frac{1}{n}\}\neq\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\{x:f(x) > 0\}$.

Comment: @AlexFrancisco This statement is on my text book, and I think it is also true, we can prove that both sides contain each other: take any element from left side, it of course belongs to the right side, so does the right side.

Comment: Short answer: to prove two sets are equal, show that anything in the left set is in the right one, and vice versa. [BTW, your two sets *are* equal.]

Comment: @JohnHughes Thank you, I think they will be equal but I am not pretty sure.

Comment: The sets in the title are equal, but as Alex mentions, the equation $$ \{x:f(x)>1/n\} =\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \{x:f(x)>0\}$$ in the body, is false. In addition to being false, it "doesn't make sense" on two levels. First, the LHS depends on $n$ while the RHS has no dependence on $n$ ($n$ appears as the union index, but that's as a *dummy* variable). Second, since $n$ does not appear in the expression $\{x:f(x)>0\}$ that the union is taken over, the union is of all the same set, thus we have $$ \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \{x:f(x)>0\} = \{x:f(x)>0\} $$ so why bother writing the $\bigcup$ at all?

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I am sorry that is a little clerical error.

Comment: @AlexFrancisco I am sorry that is a little clerical error...

Comment: @R.Sherlock Well it was pointed out and then you said 'it's in the textbook' so I wanted to make sure you knew. (It seems clear that the union should just be on the other side of the equation.)

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

First, it should be$$
\{x \mid f(x) > 0\} = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \left\{x \,\middle|\,f(x) > \frac{1}{n}\right\}.
$$

Now, it is easy to see that$$
\{x \mid f(x) > 0\} \supseteq \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \left\{x \,\middle|\,f(x) \geqslant \frac{1}{n}\right\}.
$$
And for any $x \in \{x \mid f(x) > 0\}$, suppose $n \in \mathbb{N}_+$ satisfies $n \geqslant \dfrac{1}{f(x)}$, then$$
f(x) \geqslant \frac{1}{n} \Longrightarrow x \in \left\{x' \,\middle|\,f(x') \geqslant \frac{1}{n}\right\}.
$$
Thus$$
\{x \mid f(x) > 0\} \subseteq \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \left\{x \,\middle|\,f(x) \geqslant \frac{1}{n}\right\}.
$$

Comment: Your third paragraph, "And for any $x \in ...$, suppose $n \in \Bbb N^{+}$" should read, "And for any $x \in \ldots$, there is some $n \in \Bbb N^{+}$ that satisfies [...], by the Archimedean axiom." There's no "supposing" needed here.

Comment: @JohnHughes That's why it's *suppose* instead of *assume*.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A_n =\{x : f(x) > \frac{1}{n}\}$ and $B_n = \{x : f(x) \geq \frac{1}{n}\}$.

Then its easy to see that $A_n \subset B_n$ so we have that $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n \subset \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} B_n(1)$.

Now let $x \in \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} B_n$ then there exist $n_0$ such that $x\in  B_{n_0}$. So , $f(x) \geq \frac{1}{n_0}$ now set

$n' = 2n_0 > n_0$. Then you have that $\frac{1}{n'} < \frac{1}{n_0}$  but since $f(x) \geq \frac{1}{n_0}$ you also have that $f(x) >\frac{1}{n'}$.

Which means that $x \in A_{n'} \subset \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n$. So $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} B_n \subset \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n$ (2).

And from $(1),(2)$  you have the desired equality !